# Update progress bar while iterating file structure

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker, file-search

I use this function, to search for all exe files in selected directory:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
{
    Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
    pending.Push(root);
    while (pending.Count != 0)
    {
        var path = pending.Pop();
        string[] next = null;
        try
        {
            next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
        }
        catch { }
        if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
            foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
        try
        {
            next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

How can I update the progress bar status, based on the number of files found?

Comment: Since you don't know the total number of files (or I should say, unless you know the total number of files) knowing how many you've found so far doesn't tell you what % complete you are.  Just use a marquee bar.

Comment: no, its standard windows forms application in VS 2010

Comment: The ProgressBar control requires a maximum value, this allows it to increment the UI value correctly.

Comment: If you are using .NET4+, you should be using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(...) instead of Directory.GetFiles(...). EnumerateFiles allows the list of files to be built as you need items from it and generally more performant.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you don't know the total number of exe files (aka the 100%) that you'll find so basically you CAN'T render a progress bar! For this kind of tasks it would be more suited an hourglass or a marquee bar...

Answer (score 0):

You would want to search through and then set the progressbar maximum to the number of files found.

You can assign a counter that assigns the value a = to # of files found then set

progressBar.Maximum = a;

Comment: The work that he's doing is simply finding the files.  He won't know what the maximum is until he's all done.

Comment: It would require wrapping around twice, finding all the total files to get the maximum and then to actually 'pretend' to searching for total files.

His best bet is a marquee bar with a label # of File Found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why don't you assign the Maximum of the progress bar to `pending.Count` and add 1 to the progress bar's value each time you process a file?